# Baofeng UV-5R Split mode

Tags: baofeng, uv-5r

I recently purchased the [Baofeng UV-5RA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009MAKWC0). I am trying to set up dual watch mode so that I can receive one frequency, and be able to transmit on another frequency when I key the radio.

I enabled TDR and set TDR-AB to B. When I am on frequency A and key the radio, it still transmits on A not B. I followed the instructions [here](http://brianbdonaldson.com/docs/Programming%20the%20Baofeng%20UV.pdf) and apparently it is a bug?

Has anyone else had this problem before?

EDIT: I think this has something to do with the upgraded firmware? Can someone confirm [this](http://forums.radioreference.com/budget-entry-level-transceivers/296079-baofeng-uv-5r-vs-uv-b5.html#post2233901).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due firmware. Apparently Baofeng is getting rid of that menu option.